# StatusBar at the bottom of a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, controltemplate

How can I extend Datagrid in order to have StatusBar at the bottom of it? It should be something like:

```
<CustomControl>   
     <StackPanel>
          <DataGrid></DataGrid>
          <StatusBar></StatusBar>
     </StackPanel>
</CustomControl>
```

If I will create CustomControl there will be no way i could specify DataGrid.ItemSource and DataGrid.SelectedItem when I will use that control.

But I would like to use it like that:

```
<CustomDataGrid ItemSource="{Binding Something}" SelectedItem="{Binding Otherthing}">
     <CustomDataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn/>
          <DataGridTextColumn/>
     </CustomDataGrid.Columns>
</CustomDataGrid>
```

Comment: Like a final row? Just an arbiatrary control? Please provide more information. Generally speaking I'd say, put `DataGrid` and your `StatusBar` control into a `DockPanel` and align them as desired, but without further info this is just a wild guess...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to bind to a DataGrid `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` dependency properties within a user control

here is explained how to do

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/9e4b0709-ca4e-4ed4-9fad-47ed73c120f6

The example is for `ItemsSource` but from it it should be easy to expand the code also for `SelectedItem`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thats right but I also want to declare Columns like it is simple DataGrid.